# how to add row to datagridview

Tags: c#

How to add row of tableadapter which return the result of my query (this query just return one row).

And I need to add all these rows to datagridview (during for loop)

Answer (score 1):

There is DataSource property on DataGridView. You can set results returned from your DataAdapter (DataTable?) to that property.

[DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)

Comment: /me agrees. Use the DataSource property and then add rows to your datasource instead of the DataGridView and then refesh the bindings. 

This is made easier by using a BindingSource object. Set your datasource (datable or whatever) as the Datasource of the BindingSource. Then make the DataSource of the DataGridView the BindingSource. Then to refresh the bindings you just call BindingSource.RefreshBindings().