# How can I add rows to a DataGridView control in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have created 3 columns on a `DataGridView` control, but I don't know how to add rows. Please help.

Comment: @Pedro: A `DataGridView`—see the title.

Comment: The real question is, are you *binding* the control to a data set or database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add row to datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536771/how-to-add-row-to-datagridview)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a duplicate of:
[How to add data to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923082/how-to-add-data-to-datagridview)
or
[how to add row to datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536771/how-to-add-row-to-datagridview)
or
[How to add rows and columns to a DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264916/how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-datagrid)
or
[How can I add one row to a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932275/how-can-i-add-one-row-to-a-datagridview)

Please use the search bar located on the top right corner of this site if you think your question may have already been covered.

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head..

```
DataRowItem dr = DataGrid.NewRow();
```

DataGrid.Items.Add(dr);

Comment: how is datagrid relevant to the question ?

Comment: well the question and Technology is quite vague, so i guess the answer was stating to the options he may or have close to.